# I am getting error message while working on backend of a mern project, help me out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling

```
let eId = await Order.findOne({email: req.body.email })    
    console.log(eId)
    if (eId===null) {
        try {
            await Order.create({
                email:req.body.email,
                order_data:[data]
            }).then(() => {
                res.json({ success: true })
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message,"this place error occur")
            res.send("Server Error", error.message)
        }
    }
```

while working on this code its continuously showing the below error message.

null
order validation failed: email: Path `email` is required. this place error occur
express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead

I want the solution of the error so that the required data can be put in mongodb.

Comment: The email is null or your req.body.email is null. Try debugging the value of `req.body.email`

Comment: To resolve the error, you need to ensure that the "email" field is provided in the request body and modify the response code to res.status(status).send(body)